# Fatal error:problems with ctools

Tags: module, drupal-7, drupal-ctools

> Fatal error: Class CToolsCssCache contains 1 abstract method and must
>   therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods
>   (DrupalCacheInterface::__construct) in
>   C:\wamp\www\gamenetuk\sites\all\modules\ctools\includes\css-cache.inc
>   on line 52

I got this error message on my web how can I solve this problem?

Comment: I believe you will need to upgrade your Drupal core to resolve this error. You should also include information about which version of Drupal and ctools you currently are using.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is documented here
https://www.drupal.org/node/2408217

So as stated by Cyclone you should upgrade your Drupal Core to the latest (currently 7.37) https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal

This is advisable for security reasons anyway.